# Alexa nodejs accessing url from Amazon Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I've created a simple skill for Alexa based on this example: https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-fact/blob/en-US/lambda/custom/index.js

Now, I'd like the script to log something on a different server when *GetNewFactIntent* is called.

This is what I'm trying to do but have an issue with *this* which is not what it should be in the *http.get* callback.

```
'GetNewFactIntent': function () {
//var thisisit = this;
http.get("http://example.com", function(res) {
  //console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
  const factArr = data;
  const factIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * factArr.length);
  const randomFact = factArr[factIndex];
  const speechOutput = GET_FACT_MESSAGE + randomFact;

  this.response.cardRenderer(SKILL_NAME, randomFact);
  this.response.speak(speechOutput);
  this.emit(':responseReady');
}).on('error', function(e) {
  //console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
},
```

What *this* needs to be replaced with in the example above for this to work?

Comment: I can't see an immediate problem with that code. Can you add additional information about exactly how it is failing? More context is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` will not be what you think it is, because you are in the context of the callback function. There are two possible solutions:

1. Use an arrow function instead. An arrow function preserves the `this` variable of the scope it is being used in:
   `function () { ... }` -> `() => { }`.
2. Declare `var self = this;` outside of the callback and then replace your `this` inside the callback with your `self` variable.

Example:

```
function getStuff () {
    var self = this;
    http.get (..., function () {
        // Instead of this, use self here
    })
}
```

For further information, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: I tried with _var that = this_ before but couldn't get it to work but arrow function did the trick. I didn't know that it preserves _this_ variable of the scope so it is good to know this. Many thanks.

Comment: Happy to see you could fix your problem!